# React Native Expo Push notification for specific user

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

Expo allows you to send notification by device id which is ambiguous and not great for my use case, how can i send notification that only specific user will receive? for example can i pass user id or username besides device id?

this is the body request body:

```
{
    to: pushToken, // user id or topic?
    body: 'test notification',
    data: { withSome: 'data' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a db table where you'll record user_id / username & device_token in order to be able to send notification to a user by his user_id or username.

Comment: yeah but its only accepts push tokens even when i have both i can't tell it to send to user

Comment: That's why you need to record token with user_id in a table , then get the token of the user you want to send him a notification and pass it

Comment: what if two users are using same device and I want to send it only to specific user?